# AWS Cloudfront as CDN for Heroku Site with Custom Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Recently, I bought a domain from AWS Route 53 (brianpatrickhummel.com) to host a personal portfolio. The portfolio site is up and running, using an S3 bucket and Cloudfront as a CDN. On the portfolio site, visitors are able to preview some apps that I built, which launch in-site using iframe elements, and I noticed that my Heroku-deployed apps take 10-20 seconds to load, since those sites have very few visitors on average and have no CDN service.

Therefore, I began researching using AWS Cloudfront as a CDN.  I began with one Heroku app, adding a custom domain which is now configured as such:

```
Domain Name: burger.brianpatrickhummel.com
DNS Target: burger.brianpatrickhummel.com.herokudns.com
```

The last step is to "configure your app’s DNS provider to point to the Heroku-supplied DNS Target." Between this step and properly configuring a Cloudfront distribution, I have run myself into a spiral of confusion.  I'm uncertain as to of where I make certain DNS/CNAME changes, in Cloudfront, Route 53 or both.

There isn't much online documention specifically related to these three technologies (Heroku, Cloudfront, Route 53) and I've spent much time bouncing between these three articles, to no avail:

[Heroku - Using Amazon CloudFront CDN](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn)

[Configuring Amazon Route 53 DNS for Your Heroku App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53)

I'm confident that the necessary changes are simple in nature and would greatly appreciate any insight from those who might have experience with this particular configuration.

**---UPDATE---**


I have one last question, now that I have all of my Heroku apps successfully routing through Cloudfront, I have realized that all of the apps which have components that generate POST HTTP requests receive 403 - forbidden errors. Does this have anything to do with the relative URL in the respective AJAX calls:

```
$(document).on("click", ".saveButton", function () {
  var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/save/" + thisId
  }).done(function () {}
```

I see the following in the Cloudfront documentation:

> CloudFront always caches responses to GET and HEAD requests. You can also configure CloudFront to cache responses to OPTIONS requests. CloudFront does not cache responses to requests that use the other methods.

Is this more of a problem with handling the responses from the server of the Heroku app than it is an issue with successfully sending the request?

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

I'm thinking that this has to do with HTTP/HTTPS based on this statement in the Cloudfront Documentation:

> CloudFront doesn't redirect DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, or PUT requests from HTTP to HTTPS. If you configure a cache behavior to redirect to HTTPS, CloudFront responds to HTTP DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, or PUT requests for that cache behavior with HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden).

Heroku states:

> If you are wanting to serve Cloudfront assets using SSL you can simply use HTTPS on the distribution domain given to you by Amazon. Note, whilst you can create CNAME’s for this purpose, serving Cloudfront assets over your CNAME and SSL has an attached cost.

In AWS Cloudfront Distribution Cache Behaviour settings, you can choose
for the **Viewer Protocol Policy** from three options:

> If you want CloudFront to allow viewers to access your web content using either HTTP or HTTPS, specify HTTP and HTTPS. If you want CloudFront to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS, specify Redirect HTTP to HTTPS. If you want CloudFront to require HTTPS, specify HTTPS Only.

The Cloudfront doc goes on to note:

> **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS**
>   Viewers can use both protocols, but HTTP requests are automatically redirected to HTTPS requests. CloudFront returns HTTP status code 301 (Moved Permanently) along with the new HTTPS URL. The viewer then resubmits the request to CloudFront using the HTTPS URL.
>
> When a viewer makes an HTTP request that is redirected to an HTTPS request, CloudFront charges for both requests. For the HTTP request, the charge is only for the request and for the headers that CloudFront returns to the viewer. For the HTTPS request, the charge is for the request, and for the headers and the object returned by your origin.
>
> **HTTPS Only**
>   Viewers can access your content only if they're using HTTPS. If a viewer sends an HTTP request instead of an HTTPS request, CloudFront returns HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) and does not return the object.

Good grief, I had no idea how complicated it would be to host a personal website!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Domain Name: burger.brianpatrickhummel.com

You will point this to CloudFront, in Route 53... but before you can do that, you need to create a new CloudFront distribution and configure that hostname as an Alternate Domain Name for the distribution.

> DNS Target: burger.brianpatrickhummel.com.herokudns.com

Configure this as the Origin Domain Name when creating the distribution CloudFront.

In the Cache Behavior settings, whitelist the `Host` header so that Heroku will understand which site the request is for.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I created a Cloudfront distribution with the Heroku DNS Target as the Origin Domain Name (and added the Heroku App Domain Name as a CNAME) and then created a Route 53 Record Set with the name that matched the Cloudfront CNAME, Type: A, Alias: Yes, and then selected the Cloudfront Distribution as the Alias Target.........it worked perfectly!!  I saw some people mention configuring the Route 53 Record Set Type as CNAME.  I chose Type A and it seems to work, when I tried to use CNAME, there were no selectable options in the Alias Target dropdown menu.

Comment: Excellent.  An `A` record with Alias set to Yes is the correct choice.  You can use a CNAME if you have Alias set to No, by typing the CloudFront endpoint hostname into the box, **but you don't want that**.  `A` records with Alias = Yes are approximately twice as fast to look up, and there is no charge for queries to an A record Alias that points to an AWS service like CloudFront, S3, or ELB, but CNAME queries are not free.  You'll actually have a $0.00 line item on your bill for this, and it isn't free "tier" -- these are just always free.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I would do,

Since you are already on Route 53,

> Get a free SSL from ACM

Confirm your SSL verification to the domain email address.
Make sure it looks green as below,

[image: ACM Confirmation]

> Assign it to CloudFront Endpoint with the SSL and CNAME as well

You will also see a cname will be automatically created in Route53 for this SSL endpoint.

If you ping burger.brianpatrickhummel.com, it should respond from the clound front.

[image: Cloudfront SSL]

Now setup Origins in Cloudfront to point it to your endpoint with all the cache settings needed. If you don't need cache settings, you can set them all to 0, so cloudfront will not cache any data.

In your Cloudront Pattern make sure you have  * at the end so it matches all the url pattern to forward it to your endpoint.

If your endpoint need to be secured, you can pass in additional headers from Cloudfront and make sure the request is orignating from cloudfront, rather than any public endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm uncertain as to of where I make certain DNS/CNAME changes, in
>   Cloudfront, Route 53 or both

Well since Route53 is the DNS service (not CloudFront), then you would be creating the CNAME record in Route53. You want to create a CNAME record in Route53 that points your subdomain to CloudFront. Then you need to configure CloudFront to be aware that it needs to serve that domain by configuring the Alternate Domain Name field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Host` is [no longer trusted and accepted by heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers). It will no longer link up to the site correctly

Use `Origin Custom Header` instead.

The name of the custom header will go through some parsing and casing changes, so to debug it, add in this command to print the relevant headers provided in the request.

```
puts request.headers.env.reject { |key| key.to_s.include?('.') }
```

You should see your headers in there, but probably in a different format.

For reference, my header was `X-Request-ID` (this is [recommended by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id) for its extra uses), and it was converted to `HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID`.